# if date is weekend - auto rerun the function

Tags: python

So I can generate random days in a given start-end date relationship, but, if the date happens to be a weekend - currently all I can get working is to print to the user 'it is a weekend'. What I would like to do is, if the random day IS a weekend, rerun the function so the user does not have to manually. Basically - only print out weekdays - currently, if the random day is a weekend, it prints a blank space or `None` value. Only return/print weekdays is the main goal.

Here is the code so far:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randrange

def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    random_day = randrange(delta.days)
    myresult = start + timedelta(days=random_day)
    return myresult

d1 = datetime.strptime('9/1/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
d2 = datetime.strptime('9/30/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
myresult = random_date(d1, d2)

if myresult.weekday() not in (5, 6):
    print myresult.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
else:
    print "hit a weekend"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option:

```
def random_weekday(start, end):
    date = None

    while (not date or date.weekday() in (5, 6)):
        days = randrange((end - start).days)
        date = start + timedelta(days=days)

    return date

start = datetime.strptime('9/1/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
end = datetime.strptime('9/30/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')

for i in range(20):
  print(random_weekday(start, end).strftime('%m-%d-%Y'))
```

Comment: Danil - thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for! I knew I was kinda close but could not get the formatting/syntax correct. You're timely response is much appreciated! I now just need to import the 'holidays' library to exclude those and all will be well. Appreciate the effort and knowledge you have provided! Thanks again!

Comment: Is there a clean way that I could put in some validation? For instance, don't print the same day?

Answer (score 0):

So, you need a while-loop to keep getting dates until you get one that's not a weekend, like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
from random import randrange
from datetime import timedelta

def random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    random_day = randrange(delta.days)
    myresult = start + timedelta(days=random_day)
    return myresult

    while True:

        d1 = datetime.strptime('9/1/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
        d2 = datetime.strptime('9/30/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
        myresult = random_date(d1, d2)

        if myresult.weekday() not in (5,6):
            break

    print myresult.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```